# How to mock this in jest?

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I want to mock the following:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

dynamoDb.scan(...some logic here i want to mock...);
```

So I try:

```
jest.mock("aws-sdk", () => {
  return function () {
    return {
      DynamoDB: {
        DocumentClient: function () {return {scan: function() {console.log('fake scan'}},
      },
    };
  };
});
```

But it does not work :(

```
Cannot read property 'DocumentClient' of undefined
```

Comment: Your mockImplementation itself is a function that returns a _function_, not an object - I think you have one level too many of functions. More broadly `aws-sdk` is a complex API you don't own, you probably shouldn't mock it.

Comment: You can use dynamoDB local and try your logic without mocking with some sample data. Logic / code will be same as if you were going via AWS. Only AWS credentials are mocked. See details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html