# Function as property of another function ES5

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I haven't long written es5, so I forgot. Can you help how to fix this?

```
let mock = {
  DynamoDB: function() {
    {
        send: function() {console.log('sending...')}
    }
  },
};
```

then not working.

```
let client = new mock.DynamoDB();
client.send(); // does not write to console
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A constructor function should assign to a property of `this`.

```js
let mock = {
  DynamoDB: function() {
    this.send = function() {
      console.log('sending...')
    }
  }
};

let client = new mock.DynamoDB();
client.send();
```

Comment: thanks, so ez xd

Comment: can you help me with this though:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70850477/how-to-mock-this-in-jest/70853021#70853021

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this`:

```js
let mock = {
  DynamoDB: function() {
    {
        this.send = function send(){
          console.log('sending...');
        };
    }
  },
};

let client = new mock.DynamoDB();
client.send();
```